# Running python in vscode terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to run python on vscode terminal but when i try to do so i get the following:
[image: Execution output]

I use the code runner extension and i am enabling 'run code in terminal'option.
It used to work for me, but i have tried recently to run python on windows terminal by copying the entire thing vscode generates in it's terminal when building the executable(the path and everything) and pasting it to windows terminal, didn't work.
This is what i pasted:   `C:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\tmc\vscode\mooc-programming-22\part05-27_letter_square> python -u "c:\Users\Yan\AppData\Local\tmc\vscode\mooc-programming-22\part05-27_letter_square\src\letter_square.py"`

Please tell how to fix this and if what i did is the cause, then tell me also how to run python on windows terminal without causing this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: @Tomerikoo i think the image is important and can't be replaced with just text, i don't know how to make it inline instead of a link, i simply followed the options when creating the question

Comment: Could you provide what command you pasted?

Comment: Python: building executable????? It is a script language

Comment: @NaughtyConstrictor the question is confusing because it talks about extensions and things that are *not* related to Python. To use Python in  VS Code you need to install Python first, then install the Python extension, not Code Runner. If you install Python, you can run any Python script from any console or terminal. You don't need VS Code. Executing selected Python text is the job of the Python extension. If you select some text and hit `Shift+Enter` a Python console will obpen and the text will be copied and executed

Comment: I'm use VS Code and Python professionally and never even heard of Code Runner

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, it worked, although it's not what i am looking for exactly

Comment: What *are* you looking for? Execute python scripts by double-clicking ? That's not affected by VS Code or any other text editor. You'll have to specify `python.exe` as the executable associated with `.py` files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Running python in vscode terminal directly, not in the python shell where you execute commands

Comment: And what does *that* mean? Why in the VS Code terminal instead of any console window? You can type `python script.py` in any console. Python is an interpreted language, scripts are always run by the interpreter. When you install Python, [the installer associates .py with python.exe](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable) so you can run `.py` files directly with `script.py`. Unfortunately, so do text editors and IDEs, including VS Code, which means that typing `script.py` could open the file in the editor instead of running it with `python script.py`

Comment: If you want to execute `letter_square.py` you can always go to `c:\Users\....\src` and run `python letter_square.py`. If you associate `.py` with `python` instead of VS Code, you can type `letter_square.py` in the command line. The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable) explain how to run the script with just `letter_square`. It's a different and more complex story if you want to create an actual `.exe` that doesn't require a Python installation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes exactly, tha's what vscode (or rather code runner extension) does; It creates compiled python which can be run in terminal like a c++ code for example and that's how i used to run python code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have fixed the problem actually, what i have done has created a file named "python" (with no extension) in the win32 folder. I have deleted it and it works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command pasted to the windows terminal has somehow created a file named "python" (with no extension) in the "System32" folder.
Delete the file and the problem is solved.